# Tidiest way of highlighting record if older than X days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, view, dry, helper

What is the tidiest DRY way in a Rails 3 application of highlighting a table row depending on its age?

```
<% @faults_open.each do |fault| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= fault.name %></td>  
    <td><%= fault.faulttype %></td>
    <td><%= fault.priority %></td>
    <td><%= time_ago_in_words(fault.created_at) %> ago</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', fault %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I would like a class applied to the table row with an indication of its age which I can then style using CSS.

```
<% @faults_open.each do |fault| %>
  <tr <% if fault.created_at > Date.1.week.ago %>class="weekold"<% end %>>
    <td><%= fault.name %></td>  
    <td><%= fault.faulttype %></td>
    <td><%= fault.priority %></td>
    <td><%= time_ago_in_words(fault.created_at) %> ago</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', fault %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Something like the above but obviously adding them to the view would be messy. I plan on adding a couple of ages, such as:

```
weekold
twoweeksold
monthold
sixmonthold
yearold
ancient
```

I imagine a helper is the tidiest way, but I'm unsure on how the helper would work. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently did something similar, adding a class name to the row that corresponded to it's approximate age in weeks, then I used CSS to do the actual highlighting.

Why not use a helper.. (just an example)

```
def highlight_age_class (created_at)
  @@today ||= Date.today
  num_weeks = ((@@today - created_at.to_date) / 7).floor
  class_name = "aged_#{num_weeks}_weeks"
  num_weeks == 1 ? class_name.singularize : class_name
end
```

With your HTML..

```
<tr class="<%= highlight_age_class fault.created_at %>">
```

Combined with some CSS..

```
.aged_1_week
.aged_1_weeks
.aged_4_weeks
.aged_24_weeks
.aged_56_weeks

etc
```

You can then focus on extending and optimizing your helper method for age highlighting.